# error in NetBeans for android setContentView

Tags: android, netbeans

I have the following errors after installing android sdk, and android plugin for NetBeans:
c:/Android/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:892:The following error occurred while executing this line:

c:/Android/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:894: The following error occurred while executing this line:
c:/Android/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:906: The following error occurred while executing this line:
c:/Android/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:284: null return: 2

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the environment is not properly configured to run the build. You can look into c:/Android/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:284 to see what is executed there. You may need to tell Ant where is Java installed or something similar.

Comment: I can't see build.xml:284 
there are build.xml and uibuild.xml

Comment: how can I tell ant where java is ?

Comment: The output is structured as <filename>:<linenumber>. As for the Java home: you can set environment variables or pass some properties.